# scroll to an element selenium java

Tags: java, selenium, scrollview, element

I'm trying to find an element and click on that every time but Scroll is not functioning.

```
WebElement attendeelist = dr.findElement(By.id("idView2--freemantable-tblBody"));
java.util.List<WebElement> row = attendeelist.findElements(By.tagName("tr"));

 for(int j=8;j<row.size();j++) {
     for(int k=1;k<4;k++) {
        if (j>8)
        {
            JavascriptExecutor js = (JavascriptExecutor) dr;
            js.executeScript("arguments[0].scrollIntoView(false);", dr.findElement(By.id("__item1-idView2--freemantable-"+j)));
        }
        dr.findElement(By.id("__button"+k+"-idView2--freemantable-"+j)).click(); 
        dr.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(15,TimeUnit.SECONDS);
        dr.findElement(By.id("__button4-img")).click();

    }
}
```

Please help me to fix this.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
JavascriptExecutor je = (JavascriptExecutor)driver;
je.executeScript("window.scrollBy(0,250),"");
```

first scroll down and then click on desired element.
To find exact pixel location you can use chrome extension Page Ruler and MeasureIt.

Comment: try this - make flag as TRUE -js.executeScript("arguments[0].scrollIntoView(true);", dr.findElement(By.id("__item1-idView2--freemantable-"+j)));

Answer (score 0):

have tried that too.

now i am trying with this code , For the first time it scroll down to the element and from the second time , error with element is non intractable

WebElement attendeelist = dr.findElement(By.id("idView2--freemantable-tblBody"));
             java.util.List row = attendeelist.findElements(By.tagName("tr"));

```
         for(int j=10;j<row.size();j++) {


             for(int k=1;k<4;k++) {

             if (j>=8)

                    {
                         dr.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(15,TimeUnit.SECONDS);
                         WebElement Element = dr.findElement(By.id("__button"+k+"-idView2--freemantable-"+j+"-content"));
                         js.executeScript("arguments[0].scrollIntoView();", Element);  
                         dr.findElement(By.id("__button"+k+"-idView2--freemantable-"+j+"-content")).click(); 
                         dr.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(15,TimeUnit.SECONDS);
                         dr.findElement(By.id("__button4-img")).click();
                    }
                    }
                    }
                    }

     dr.findElement(By.id("idView2--combobox1-arrow")).click();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this method:

```
public void scrollToWebElement(String locator) {
 try {
        (new WebDriverWait(driver, 20)).until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(elementlocator.elements(locator)));
        WebElement element = driver.findElement(elementlocator.elements(locator));
        Point point = element.getLocation();
        JavascriptExecutor jsExecutor = ((JavascriptExecutor) driver);
        int y = point.getY() - 200;
        jsExecutor.executeScript("window.scrollTo(" + point.getX() + "," + y + ");", "");
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace(); public void scrollToWebElement(String locator) {
    }
}
```